# Intershop Enfinity Suite 6 API specs / docs / info

Tags: api, module, documentation, specifications, intershop

we're working with a client who's parent company is using intershop enfinity 6 as a shopping platform with each sub-brand using their own shops, but they are connected to the "mothership" via some form of api.

now i am facing several problems:

- i have no influence on what software is used whatsoever, so i know enfinity is probably a pain in the ass but i have to live with that
- i will be old and grey until they manage to get me some contact or documentation from the parent company's it department
- apparently there is no chance of acquiring documentation from intershop without being a registered customer. at least i found nothing on their site but the brief mention of "modularity"...

all i want to do is to look up what kind of api (or whatever they use to implement shopping functionality on other sites) this is and if it is in some way standardized, etc... any info helps.

is there anyone with experience on this? i'm sure to get some specs someday but it would be nice to come a bit prepared.

thanks in advance,
anton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get detailed information only if you have a support / customer account with Intershop. Or you get your hands on an install DVD provided by your client - there you can find a whole set of documents and API documentation. The best information until then would be visiting http://www.intershop.com/enfinity-functionality.html - but it just talk about features, not technology.
(Disclaimer: I work for Intershop)